# Как эмулировать диски формата не iso в vmware fusion на macbook?

Tags: macos, vmware

Есть ли возможность эмулировать виртуальный диск на mac os с образом например nrg или bin cue, чтобы его затем смог прочитать VMware fusion?
Он воспринимает только образы iso. Пробовал daemon tools, виртуальный привод создается, но его нельзя выбрать в vmware.

Comment: Сконвертируйте в iso и не мучайтесь. Вы же не думаете когда авто требуется AI 98, а у вас только нефть. Конечно прикрутить аппарат можно, но для того чтобы доехать до заправки думаю это лишнее.

Comment: А для начала - просто попробуйте сменить расширение с NRG на ISO. Если NRG не RAW - сработает.

Comment: @Akina интересно а смысл  Nero переименовывать открытый формат. Если верить вам. Ведь интерес не в самих файлах которые видны а в загрузочных секторах

Comment: @AzizUmarov А это не ко мне вопросы. Но голый факт - из полусотни имеющихся у меня NRG все софтовые и четверть мультимедиа-образов прекрасно подключаются через Gizmo как виртуальные после переименования.

Comment: @Akina против вас ничего не имею, но почитайте тут https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NRG_(file_format)#:~:text=An%20NRG%20file%20is%20a,used%20to%20store%20disc%20images.&text=For%20example%2C%20Alcohol%20120%25%2C,not%20ISO%20images%20with%20a%20. Contrary to popular belief, NRG files are not ISO images with a .nrg extension and a header attached.

Comment: @AzizUmarov Если теория противоречит практике - нафиг теорию. А википедики порой такого понапишут... Ну или, скажем, гизмо умеет игнорировать хедер - почему совсем нет?

Answer (score 1):

Сконвертируйте в iso и не мучайтесь. тулов по типу (http://www.nrgtoiso.com/) тонна. Вы же не думаете о том что нужен аппарат когда авто требуется AI 98, а у вас только нефть . Конечно прикрутить аппарат можно, но для того чтобы доехать до заправки думаю это лишнее.

Мнение моё личное может не совпадать вашим, в холивар не звать. **Всем Удачи!!!!**

Comment: Я так попробовал, но не воспроизводится музыка. В одной из утилит так и было сказано, что при конвертации музыкальные треки не будут сохранены.
А если записать болванку в windows, и через внешний оптический привод попробовать запустить в mac? Так может сработать?

Comment: Кстати это и есть конвертация про100 через Nero. Посмотрите ещё в Nero сохранить образ как ISO. и будет вам Мир и Покой

Comment: А где там такая опция? У меня после открытия образа его только на диск можно записать.

Comment: https://youtu.be/mthBs2YE0O4

Comment: @manking ну что помогло?

Comment: Нет, у меня там по другому окно отображалось в nero. По всякому пробовал. PowerIso тоже запрещал сохранять в ISO образ с музыкальными треками. Пока помогла только запись на реальный cd-r диск и подключение внешнего привода к ноуту.

Comment: Возьмите UltraIso и создайте образ из диска. Попытайте счастье